# Apache, настройка виртуальных хостов?

Tags: apache, virtual, localhost, сервер

на данный момент apache настроен на 1 сайт, как расширить виртуальные хосты? Я добавил в htppd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>    ServerName mysite.ru    ServerAlias www.mysite.ru    DocumentRoot www/vhosts/mysite.ru/httpdocs    ErrorLog logs/mysite.ru-error.log</VirtualHost>
```

естественно создал папку vhosts в папке www, затем в vhosts создал папку-сайт mysite.ru и в ней httpdocs, в котором и лежит индексный файл, теперь перейдя по адресу mysite.ru в бразуере открывается сайт с интернета, естественно это все из-за hosts, который я исправил дописав 127.0.0.1 mysite.ru, но перезапустив apache и перейдя опять к mysite.ru браузер мне выгружает вообще mainsite.ru, т.е. index того файла, который лежит в папке www.

Вопрос - что ему еще надо чтобы он виртуальные хосты принял?

Comment: ОС какая???

Comment: Windows XP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80># локальный адрес    ServerName mysite.ru    ServerAlias www.mysite.ru    DocumentRoot "c:/.../www/vhosts/mysite.ru/httpdocs"# указать полный путь    ErrorLog logs/mysite.ru-error.log</VirtualHost>
```

Попробуйте описать "vhost" точнее.

Comment: спасибо, дей-но полный путь решает!

Comment: ой, поспешил я, теперь другие хосты открывает как mysite.ru

Comment: Добавьте так же виртуальный хост и для mainsite.ru.